# Monte Carlo simulation programming exercise

Tags: python

I'm doing a programming exercise in Python. I'm getting a PI that's way too high (around 3.90), but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Is it an imprecision in the included functions or am I making some sort of a logical error?

**Exercise**

Monte Carlo simulation uses random numbers and probability to solve problems. This function has a wide range of applications in computational mathematics, physics, chemistry, and finance. This exercise gives an example of using Monte Carlo simulation for estimating  π.

To estimate π using the Monte Carlo function, draw a circle with its bounding square as shown below.

[image: A circle inside a square]

Assume the radius of the circle is 1. Therefore, the circle area is π and the square area is 4. Randomly generate a point in the square. The probability for the point to fall in the circle is circleArea / squareArea =  π / 4.

Write a program that randomly generates 1,000,000 points in the square and let numberOfHits denote the number of points that fall in the circle. Thus, numberOfHits is approximately 1000000 * (π / 4). π can be approximated as 4 * numberOfHits / 1000000. Write the complete program for estimating π.

**My code**

```
import math
import random

RADIUS_OF_CIRCLE = 1
LENGTH_OF_SQUARE = 2

def giveRandomArea():
    xCoordinate = random.random()
    yCoordinate = random.random()
    randomArea = abs(xCoordinate * yCoordinate)
    return randomArea

def main():
    areaOfCircle = math.pi * RADIUS_OF_CIRCLE ** 2 
    areaOfSquare = LENGTH_OF_SQUARE * LENGTH_OF_SQUARE

    count = 0
    numberOfHits = 0

    while count < 1000000:
        if giveRandomArea() <= (areaOfCircle / areaOfSquare):
            numberOfHits += 1
        count += 1

    print("pi is approximately", 4 * numberOfHits / 1000000)

main()
```

Comment: You did not understand the assignment correctly. The function giveRandomArea() must check if the point is inside or outside, not calculate the product of the coordinates (which is meaningless). Likewise, you use the results produced by this function incorreclty.

Comment: You can't use PI to compute PI. :-)

Comment: You bump `numberOfHits` if `(x*x+y*y) <= 1`.  That's how you tell whether a point is inside or not.